# min cost of climbing stairs dynamic programming

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve the following problem on leetcode:

```
On a staircase, the i-th step has some non-negative cost cost[i] assigned (0 indexed). 
Once you pay the cost, you can either climb one or two steps. 
You need to find minimum cost to reach the top of the floor, and you can either start 
from the step with index 0, or the step with index 1.
```

My solution is shown below:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int minCostClimbingStairs(vector<int>& cost) {
        return helper(cost, cost.size() - 1);
    }

    int helper(vector<int>& cost, int currStair) {
        static vector<double> minCost(cost.size(), 0);
        minCost[0] = cost[0];
        minCost[1] = cost[1];
        if (minCost[currStair] > 0) {
            return minCost[currStair];
        }

        return minCost[currStair] = min(helper(cost, currStair - 1), helper(cost, currStair - 2)) + cost[currStair];
    }
};
```

When I try to submit, I get the following run-time error. Why?

`AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x603000000008 at pc 0x0000004089af bp 0x7ffdd02dcaa0 sp 0x7ffdd02dca98`

EDITED SOLUTION:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int minCostClimbingStairs(vector<int>& cost) {
        return helper(cost, cost.size() - 1);
    }

    int helper(vector<int>& cost, int currStair) {
        if (currStair < 0 || cost.size() <= 1) {
            return 0;
        }

        static vector<double> minCost(cost.size(), 0);
        minCost[0] = cost[0];
        minCost[1] = cost[1];

        if (minCost[currStair] > 0) {
            return minCost[currStair];
        }

        minCost[currStair] = min(helper(cost, currStair - 1), helper(cost, currStair - 2)) + cost[currStair];

        return min(minCost[cost.size()-1], minCost[cost.size()-2]);
    }
};
```

As you can see I made changes in the end of the code

Comment: is there any solution using recursion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a missing base case for the recursion. `currStair` keeps decrementing by -1 or -2 in each recursive call, but there's no condition to check if it went below 0 and cut off the recursion, resulting in an illegal memory access like `minCost[-1]`.

Add the precondition

```
if (currStair < 0) return 0;
```

and you're back on track, although the algorithm still has correctness issues to resolve.

Here's a hint that might help you get unstuck:

> The instructions say: "You need to find minimum cost to reach the top of the floor, and you can either start from the step with index 0, or the step with index 1."

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. Can you check my edited solution above? I'm still stuck but I know where the problem is. I just am not sure how to fix it. (If say the input was [1,3], I'm returning 3 because I don't compare it to the first cost)

Comment: Great--feel free to point me to it when you post it. I'm assuming you've looked at the hint, but think about how this code handles the "you can start at 0 or 1" option. Does your code do this? Also, is there a particular reason you've decided to work from the back to the front? I think the algorithm is less intuitive written this way because it doesn't match the problem description.

Comment: thank you very much I'll let you know when I do. I decided to implement it top-down just to practice both ways of doing it.

Comment: here is the link to my new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59230399/wrong-answer-to-dynamic-programming-problem-of-finding-minimum-stair-cost